# Python exec() Permission Denied in Apache server: /cgi_bin/*.py

Tags: python, permissions, apache2, cgi, exec

I have 2 python env in my server. One path is `/usr/bin` and other one is the anaconda path as shown below. I am getting Permission denied error when I try executing a basic Python script on my Apache server. The python interpreter path in my .py file is as follows

```
#!/home/cloudera/anaconda3/bin
```

When this path is used, the apache server shows the error as shown below:

> (13)Permission denied: exec of '/var/www/cgi-bin/abc.py' failed, referer:

When my python interpreter path in .py is changed to i.e `#!/usr/bin` it works well.

The problem is I have installed all my packages in `/home/cloudera/anaconda3/bin`

I tried setting this path to be accessible to execute in apache server by adding the below line of code in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file as follows

```
  <Directory "/home/cloudera/anaconda3/bin/">
    AllowOverride None
    Options ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .py
    #None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I still get Permission Denied. It still does not work. I am new to cgi, any help would be really grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: shoudn't it be `#!/home/cloudera/anaconda3/bin/python` ?

Comment: Ha, I thought this was related to privilege separation... but yes, calling exec on a dir as an interpreter would also get `EACCESS`. Should have read it more carefully. :)

Comment: "When my python interpreter path in .py is changed to i.e #!/usr/bin it works well." I doubt it.... please review those comments, add "python" and see what happens

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre the changes to python interpreter path  #!home/cloudera/anaconda3/bin to #!../bin/python seems to be same, Thanks :)

Comment: @OndrejK. I understand the error message by your response, but i am not sure how to access the path, the configuration was just a trial, I am not sire about it, any leads would be really helpful.

Comment: @NMS I've tried, but I freely admit, I am not best at explaining stuff. :) ping me if it didn't help.

Comment: @OndrejK. thanks for your reply. My server was down so couldn't reply you back yesterday. I tried to tweak into your answer. The User and Group in my httpd.conf was apache and I tried to change it to the user and group which could access and execute the file from command line. The user does not have su access, will that be a problem? or do I need to use apache user itself? Thanks :)

Comment: The user does not need to be able to use you do not need to be able to change to that user (it might help you look around through "its eyes"), but is unlikely to be even enabled without further tweaks as mentioned. You can think of the apache server doing the `su` part to access thing in your filesystem.

Comment: Thanks a lot @OndrejK. I get a complete picture now. This is what i tried.. 
1. Changed ownership to apache user: "apache" and gave owner-write access
    `sudo chown apache:apache /home/cloudera/anaconda3
     chmod 744 /home/cloudera/anaconda3`

2. Added apache user to cloudera group, later gave write permission to group

  `sudo usermod -a -G apache cloudera
   chmod 764 /home/cloudera/anaconda3`

Comment: @OndrejK. When I tried the command setenforce 0 to turn off SELinux it works fine. But that is not what I want. I feel I am missing the permissions or some configuration mess up. Can u please guide me to troubleshoot or give few hints, please. I am new to this.

Comment: @NMS: Regarding SELinux. Yes, that can get in your way. Sorry, completely forgot that is around for some distros too. Unfortunately, I neither could be much help with that, nor is this likely the correct forum. I'd try the Linux and Unix community? ON the one before. The permbits look off. Namely the ones for user group and others. They are inconsistent with user (which has exec bit) and do not seem to be entirely useful on a directory as this should prevent them from accessing its content.

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly I've completely missed the fact that the interpret was specified as directory and the actual binary file as pointed out by [Jean-François Fabre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6451573/jean-fran%c3%a7ois-fabre). That would indeed cause the same error. But since the OP fixed that and still got the same error, I am undeleting the answer extended as requested.

Also come to think of it, it may be more of a [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) question as it would appear.

---

This error (`13: EACCES`) is raised by and propagated from the OS.

HTTPd servers usually employ privilege separation and once bound to a reserved port drop their EUID to an unprivileged user. Usually a dedicate one or nobody (on my system it would be user `apache`, group `apache`). You should be able to find these in your `httpd.conf` under `User` and `Group` resp.

Make sure this user has access and can execute the binary you're calling.

---

Give you've fixed the interpreted (and the file would execute on its own). Go find your `httpd.conf` file (I think different distros may package it differently, on mine it would reside here: `/etc/httpd/httpd.conf`). You will find [`User`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_unixd.html#user) and [`Group`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_unixd.html#group) entries there. You must be able to access and execute the script (incl. the interpreter) as this user, because that's how Apache will try to call it. I.e. this user (or group) must be able to access this file (along the complete path) and execute it. If for instance `/home/cloudera/` us restricted to (`0700: rwx------`) and owned by user other then the one listed int your `httpd.conf` (very likely), OS would prevent your Apache user to access and execute the file resulting in `EACCES` error you are seeing. The easiest might be to become that user and see how far your access goes, but you'd need to temporarily tweak few bits for that as the Apache account likely is locked and has not shell set (or rather `/bin/false` as shell).

---

One more thing, but I hope it's not as obvious as that. The corresponding user must have execute permission on the script itself.